# C# Replacing "/ with " - double quote backlash with double quote and others

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse some HTML that has a bunch of escaped chars inside it, a lot of 
\t, \n, \r, and every double quote is escaped by a backslash. Sample HTML:

```
<div id=\"error-modal\" title=\"Retrieving Document Error\" class=\"text-hide\">\n    We're sorry, we were unable to retrieve your requested document or image.</div>
```

I'm trying to replace these characters by doing this:

```
 var xpar = new XML.Parser(wConn.RawString.Replace("\\n", "").Replace("\\t", "").Replace("\\r","").Replace("\\\"", "\""))
```

The parser errs out because there's something else in the HTML it doesn't like, but in the exception the string is the same as it was before, the backslashes are all still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those backslashes are really there? It might be the debugger that is displaying the string with escaped quotes etc.

Comment: Use  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) and  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string).  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that replacement method take \n \r \t as a code and not as text that you want.

You can use a regular expressions to achieve that.

```
var patternToMatch = "\\\\(n|r|t|\\\")";
var replacement = "";
var escapedString = Regex.Replace(inputString, patternToMatch, replacement);
```

modify the pattern to match with your requirements but basically this expression can solve your problem.